# No speed gain adding processors to python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Cannot speed up total calculation time by adding more processors to multiprocessing. Takes just as long to run with 3 processors vs 7 processors.

I've tried chunking the data so each processors works on a much larger set of calculation. Same result.
I've initialized the static data to each process instead of passing as argument.
I've tried returning DataFrame to pool.map vs writing it out to file.
I've timed the EvalContract section. With 3 processors it takes 1 contract with 1 scenario 35 seconds to complete. With 7 processors running the same contract and scenario takes 55 seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools as it

def initializer(Cont,Scen,RandWD,dicS):
    global dfCleanCont
    global dfScen
    global dfWithdrawalRandom
    global dicSensit
    dfCleanCont = Cont
    dfScen = Scen
    dfWithdrawalRandom = RandWD
    dicSensit = dicS

def ValueProj(ContScen):
    Contract = dfCleanCont.loc[ContScen[0]]
    PTS = Contract.name
    ProjWDs = dfWithdrawalRandom[Contract['WD_ID']]
    dfScenOneSet = dfScen[dfScen["Trial"]==ContScen[1]]
    '''Do various projection calculations. All calculation in numpy arrays then converted to DataFrame before returning. Dataframe shape[601,35]'''
    return dfContProj

def ReserveProjectionPreprocess(Scen,dfBarclayRates,dicProjOuterSeries,liProjValContract):
    Timestep = liProjValContract[0]['Outer_t']
    dfInnerLoopScen = SetupInnerLoopScenarios(Timestep,Scen,dicSensit)
    BBC = BuildBarclayCurve(Timestep,Scen[Scen['Timestep']==Timestep][dicSensit['irCols']].iloc[0].to_list(),dfBarclayRates.loc[Timestep],dicSensit)
    '''Do various inner loop projection calculations, up to 601 timesteps. All calculation in numpy arrays.'''
    return pd.Series({'PTS': Contract.name,
                    'OuterScenNum': ContractValProjOne['OuterScenNum'],
                    'Outer_t': ContractValProjOne['Outer_t'],
                    'Reserve': max(PVL-ContractValProjOne['MV']-AssetHaircut,0)})

def EvalContract(liCS):
    for CS in liCS:
        '''Evaluate single contract with single scenario'''
        start_time = time.time()
        dfOuterLoop = ValueProj(CS)
        Contract = dfCleanCont.loc[CS[0]]
        PTS = Contract.name
        dfScenOneSet = dfScen[dfScen["Trial"]==CS[1]]
        dfOuterLoopCut = dfOuterLoop[dfOuterLoop['BV']!=0][:-1]
        MinMVt = dicSensit['ProjectionYrs']*12 if sum(dfOuterLoop[(dfOuterLoop['MV']==0) & (dfOuterLoop['Outer_t']>0)]['Outer_t'])==0 else min(dfOuterLoop[(dfOuterLoop['MV']==0) & (dfOuterLoop['Outer_t']>0)]['Outer_t'])
        MinBVt = dicSensit['ProjectionYrs']*12 if sum(dfOuterLoop[(dfOuterLoop['BV']==0) & (dfOuterLoop['Outer_t']>0)]['Outer_t'])==0 else min(dfOuterLoop[(dfOuterLoop['BV']==0) & (dfOuterLoop['Outer_t']>0)]['Outer_t'])
        dicProjOuterSeries = {'Contract': Contract,
                            'BaseLapsePartContribution': dfOuterLoop['BaseLapsePartContribution'].values,
                            'BaseLapsePartNetTransfer': dfOuterLoop['BaseLapsePartNetTransfer'].values,
                            'BaseLapsePartWithdrawal': dfOuterLoop['BaseLapsePartWithdrawal'].values,
                            'PrudentEstDynPartWDPct': dfOuterLoop['PrudentEstDynPartWDPct'].values,
                            'KnownPutQueueWD': dfOuterLoop['KnownPutQueueWD'].values,
                            'BaseLapsePlanSponsor': dfOuterLoop['BaseLapsePlanSponsor'].values,
                            'PrudentEstDynPlanWDPct': dfOuterLoop['PrudentEstDynPlanWDPct'].values,
                            'MonthlyDefaultCharge': dfOuterLoop['MonthlyDefaultCharge'].values,
                            'Outer_t_Maturity': min(MinMVt,MinBVt)-1}
        liProjValContract=[]
        for _,row in dfOuterLoopCut.iterrows():
            liProjValContract.append([row])

        func=partial(ReserveProjectionPreprocess,dfScenOneSet,dicProjOuterSeries)
        dfReserve = pd.concat(map(func,liProjValContract),axis=1,ignore_index=True).T
        dfOuterLoopwRes = pd.merge(dfOuterLoop,dfReserve,how='left',on=['PTS','OuterScenNum','Outer_t'])
        dfOuterLoopwRes['Reserve'].fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
        fname='OuterProjection_{0}_{1}.parquet'.format(PTS,CS[1])
        dfOuterLoopwRes.to_parquet(os.path.join(dicSensit['OutputDirOuterLoop'],fname),index=False)
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfCleanCont = 'DataFrame of 150 contract data. Each row is a contract with various info such as market value, interest rate, maturity date, etc. Indentifier index is "PTS". Shape[150,41]
    dfScen = 'DataFrame of interest rate scenarios. 100 scenarios("Trial"). Each scenario has 601 timesteps and 11 interest rate term points. Shape[60100,13]'
    liContID = list(dfCleanCont.index)
    liScenID = dfScen["Trial"].unique()
    liCS = list(it.product(liContID,liScenID))

    pool=mp.Pool(7,initializer,(ns.dfCleanCont,ns.dfScen,dfWithdrawalRandom,dicSensit,))
    n=10
    liCSGroup=[liCS[x:x+n] for x in range(0,len(liCS),n)]
    dfCombOuterProj = pd.concat(pool.map(func=EvalContract,iterable=liCSGroup))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Expecting significant speed gain with more processors. There's a bottleneck somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Tried cProfile but getting the same cumulative time with 3 or 7 processors.

Comment: The first argument to `Pool` is processes not processors. This is the number of processes (workers) that will be used to run the work.

The physical hardware will limit the amount of parallelism that can be made possible.

Running 1 million processes doesn't mean that the physical hardware has more capability of executing the processes. In real usage, there is an inflection point where additional processes will decrease performance due to context switching.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. I have 8 physical processors and only allocating 7. The chunk size of n=10 determines how many jobs to run.

Comment: You aren’t allocating 7 processors. You are allocating 7 processes. As a quick example, you can allocate 100 processes. It is not dependent on the physical hardware.

Comment: Oh. I've misunderstood what that meant. I've always seen others set this value to num_processes = mp.cpu_count() - 1 so I thought it was processors. What the best way to get to ideal number of processes without having to do many trials?

Comment: There isn't any.

Comment: Back to your original problem. There are a lot of gotchas when trying to achieve parallelism. For example, when using multiprocessing, any data being moved into the spawned process needs to be serialized and deserialized using pickle. Your example is not exactly complete. However, I can assume that the data size is large. This could be what issue you are seeing with the bad performance.